# Is there a general way to get the argument of a function in python?

Tags: python, function

```
thing = ThisIsAFunction(stuff)
```

Is there a general way to define a function that, when inputting `thing` as a parameter, will return `stuff`?

Comment: This is called an invertible function. It's not easy in general to define such a function.

Comment: This could be implemented using a class that stores the value of `stuff`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? It sounds like you may have discarded some data you needed to keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no.

There's no inbuilt syntax that supports this kind of thing, called inversion. The inverse of a function, is where you input the answer of the other function and it gives you the answers.

**Why?**

Think of the simple case of `x^2`

```
def square_it(x):
    return x**2
```

If you put in -1 or 1 you would get 1. How do you map it back? It requires a one to one mapping also. In mathematics this is called being [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). Since all functions don't have this it's not part of syntax.

Comment: Also of note, in Python, not even `def add1(x): return x + 1` is fully invertible: if the output is 2, the input could have been 1, or it could have been `True`.

Comment: Good point in terms of many to one mapping of Python's loose typing.

Answer (score 3):

You could find `stuff` *after* running the code in your question if, *before* you run that code, you first wrap your function with a wrapper that caches previous results:

```
class FunCache:
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, argument):
        result = self.fun(argument)
        self.cache[result] = argument
        return result

    def getLastArgument(self, result):
        return self.cache[result]

ThisIsAFunction = FunCache(ThisIsAFunction)

thing = ThisIsAFunction(stuff)
stuff == ThisIsAFunction.getLastArgument(thing)
```

Depending on your use case, there could be many ways you could improve on this or make it work for that case: weak cache, decorator, monkeypatching an external library, storing lists of recent arguments, etc. Of course, this is only a solution if your function is called with the argument before you need to get the argument.

Answer (score 2):

As @AER said, in general, there's no inbuilt syntax that supports this kind of thing. I strongly agree with him.

However, there is a python package that support mathematical problems [here](https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/), but I would still suggest you to write that inverse function by yourself.

Comment: "Is there a **general** way" This only works on mathematical functions, and not even most of those. It's far from general.

Comment: Cool find, I'm guessing this is only for mathematical functions though. And what does it do in the case of many to one? Given I'm guessing it uses an analytic solution to find the answer.

Comment: Edited, this is not the answer for "a general way". I'll keep this here for the information. Next time, I'll put it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

No:

```
def ThisIsAFunction(stuff):
    return 4
```

Now you'll always basically be calling `thing(4)` no matter what `stuff` was.

Comment: Maybe rewrite `thing(4)` as `ReverseFunction(4)` or something. This is a straightforward answer, but it took me a moment to understand what `thing` refers to.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: After a meaningful discussion with @JosephSible in the comments, I would like to note that my answer applies to finding an **inverse**, which is not necessarily required for what the question asks for—the use case in the question would only require a **left inverse** to be found.

That said, for it to be possible to find the argument from a function, that function will only need to be **injective** and not necessarily surjective.

---

As others have stated, such an inverse only exists if the function is bijective, meaning it is both surjective and injective. A good and simple explanation can be found [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html), but effectively what is important is that the the function only returns a certain output for one and only one specific input.

For example, a function:

```
def abs(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return -x
```

would have the same output `abs(x) = 1` for `x = 1` or `x = -1`. This means that given `abs` and `abs(x) = 1`, it is not possible to determine what value of `x` was used.

Also, even if these conditions were fulfilled, it is not possible to use a general method to find such an inverse. Subroutines in programming are simply a sequence of instruction to determine the output from an input, and these steps are more often than not nontrivial to reverse. Computers generally can't do such "algebra" for you, so you will have to look at each function individually and determine its inverse before implementing it.

Comment: "such an inverse only exists if the function is bijective" Incorrect. It only needs to be injective, not surjective. "such a function needs to be a idempotent" Also incorrect. `lambda x: (x, "Foo")` is neither surjective nor idempotent, but obviously has an inverse.

Comment: That is not true. If the function is injective and not surjective, indeed an inverse would exist from the image of the function to the domain of the function, but not from the codomain to the domain as an inverse is defined.

Comment: Who says it needs to exist from the whole codomain?

Comment: Practically, it doesn't. In practical situations, you only need to restrict the codomain to the image in order to have a well defined inverse. However, a function `f : X -> Y` with X being the domain and Y being the codomain will have the inverse defined as `f^-1 : Y -> X`.

Comment: @JosephSible Regarding your edit about idempotence, is your counter example `lambda x: (x, "Foo")` not idempotent? Successive calls to that function with the same argument will indeed return the exact same result every time.

Comment: Idempotence means f(f(x)) = f(x) for all x. Two layers of tuples clearly isn't the same as one.

Comment: You're right about the idempotence. I realised I was using idempotence to mean that successive calls would not change the state of the program and would return the same value.

Comment: @CH it makes sense if you're using the RESTful framework intuition, here it's different unfortunately. Interesting point about the state of the machine though.

Comment: "such a function needs to be non-dependent on program state, otherwise successive calls to the same function with the same input may not yield the same result" Still wrong. `lambda x: (x, datetime.now(), someOtherRandomGlobal)` It doesn't need to always yield the same result for it to have an inverse.

Comment: @JosephSible I've realised that our disagreement regarding the requirement for successive calls to yield the same result as well as regarding the codomain vs image stems from whether we are talking about left inverses only or right inverses as well. If we restrict ourselves to left inverses, you are absolutely right on both counts. However, for the right inverse to exist, the function must indeed be bijective and the counterexamples you kindly provided do not have a right inverse. (Do let me know if I am wrong regarding this!)

**EDIT**: The first does have a right inverse but not the other.

Comment: Indeed, that would be it. The question doesn't contain the word "inverse" at all, and my guess from my reading of it is that the asker only wants a left inverse.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Seems that my thought process went from seeing the problem to deciding that meant an inverse was needed, and then forgetting completely about the initial question. Thank you for the meaningful discussion, and I'll make an edit to acknowledge the problems with my answer.

Comment: Whilst idempotence may not be the best term (as the condition is probably stricter), the state of other interacting parts of the machine is crucial, and may contribute to a different answer.

Comment: @AER I think in the context of this question there's no need for such a requirement as long as the input is recoverable solely from the output. In other words, as long as it is injective it should be possible.

Comment: I'd disagree. A function can call a global variable, which it may change, and may reuse, and thus have a different output. You were alluding to an interesting point, but perhaps not the best term was used.

Comment: @AER Yes, that is indeed what I was thinking of initially when I mentioned idempotence. However as JosephSible has shown in counterexamples, idempotence is not required for the input to be recovered from the output. Hence I think the important point here is that the input is recoverable from the output—any changes to the output based on machine state need to not affect this recoverability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202611/discussion-between-aer-and-ch).